# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218: Laravel

Tags: laravel

Im having trouble posting my form to my database using laravel. When i click submit, it shows me the error MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218. My HTML code is shown below. I have defined the routes as shown below and I have also pasted my PostController which contains the store function.

```
<div class="blog-page blog-content-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <div class="blog-single-content bordered blog-container">
                    <div class="blog-comments">
                        <h3 class="sbold blog-comments-title">Leave A Comment</h3>
                        <form method="post" action="store">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control c-square"> </div>                      
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea name="body" rows="8" name="message" placeholder="Write comment here ..." class="form-control c-square"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn blue uppercase btn-md sbold btn-block">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my route page

```
 Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
```

This is the PostController which contains the store function which is suppose to store the data into the database.

```
public function store(Request $request)
        {
            //Validate the data
            $this->Validate($request, array(
                'title'=>'required|max:255',
                'body'=>'required'
                ));

            //Store the data into the database
            $post = new Post;
            $post->title = $request->get('title');
            $post->body = $request->get('body');
            $post->save();

            //redirect to another page
            return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your ```routes.php```?

Comment: Try this route: Route::post('store', 'PostController@store')

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<form method="post" action="store">
```

You should put `posts` here:

```
<form method="post" action="posts">
```

You can see all routes created with `Route::resource()` by using `php artisan route:list` command. Here, you need to look at URI created for `posts.store` route.

Also, you need to add [CSRF token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-introduction) to your form:

```
<form method="post" action="posts">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<form method="post" action="store">` will send you to the path `store` which you do not have, your form should post to the same url, like this:

```
<form method="post" action=".">
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much it works. may i ask how does laravel know that it should call my store function in order to post to the database? What if I want laravel to execute another process function called processInformation? what should i put the action as? Thank you

Comment: See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers). Basically by using `Route::resource('posts', 'PostController')`, it generates all the routes mentioned in the table in the docs. If you want to add another single route e.g. processInformation, follow the steps in [Basic Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#basic-controllers), e.g. `Route::get('posts/processInformation', 'PostController@processInformation')` and put that before your `Route::resource(...)`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<form method="post" action="posts">
```